# How does an ORM model definition bind column attributes to actual columns?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how ORMs are able to resolve table columns via a class attribute without explicitly providing table and column names.

```
from orm import Column

class Car(Model):
    id = Column()
```

Queries then are able to do this:

```
Car.select().where(Car.id == 7)
```

I understand that Column defines a method for the `__eq__` operator, but how would a column instance know it is referring to class `Car` and attribute `id` (assuming those are used for table and column names by default)?

I'm learning a lot about python by digging into how ORM libs work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SqlAlchemy and DJango ORM, the base class (`Model` here) is tie to a metaclass or a factory method (like `__new__`) which performs introspection.

Here is how you can reproduce with a function (simpler solution):

```
class Model():
    pass


class Column():
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name


def setup_class(cls):
    for name, value in cls.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(value, Column):
            attr = getattr(cls, name)
            attr.name = attr.name or name
```

This `setup_class` function introspect the *cls* class and setup the *name* attribute if it is empty or `None`, for instance:

```
class Car(Model):
    id = Column()


from pprint import pprint
pprint(Car.id.name)
# -> None

setup_class(Car)
pprint(Car.id.name)
# -> 'id'
```

**Edit**

implementation example using metaclass:

```
class Column():
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name


class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for name, col in attrs.items():
            if isinstance(col, Column):
                col.name = col.name or name
        return super(MyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class Model(metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass


class Car(Model):
    id = Column()


import pprint
pprint.pprint(Car.id.name)
# -> 'id'
```

Of course, that's not enough. You have to understand that `Column` is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). This descriptor is used to build the SQL queries.

Comment: I knew I was missing some magic. Had never encountered metaclasses before. Thanks Laurent!